# Извлечение списка из xml с использованием SimpleFramework

Tags: java, xml, парсер, simpleframework

Есть такой xml файл:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <ServiceDataModel xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <DataTypeName>Test</DataTypeName>
        <Producer>1</Producer>
        <Iin>Test</Iin>
        <Bin>Test</Bin>
        <Kato>0</Kato>
        <DataValues>
            <ServiceDataStructModelOfInt32>
                <Key>F_014110</Key>
                <Value>1</Value>
            </ServiceDataStructModelOfInt32>
            <ServiceDataStructModelOfInt32>
                <Key>F_014110110</Key>
                <Value>20</Value>
            </ServiceDataStructModelOfInt32>
            <ServiceDataStructModelOfInt32>
                <Key>F_014110120</Key>
                <Value>0</Value>
            </ServiceDataStructModelOfInt32>
        </DataValues>
    </ServiceDataModel>
```

я написал парсер и джава класс внутри описал все теги, моя программка должна парсить и посадить в базу до тега `DataValues` она без ошибки парсит, а здесь `ServiceDataStructModelOfInt32` ломается. у меня не получается написать цикл.

Это код для пасадки в базу.

```
if(request.getDataTypeName().equals("Test")){
 ps = con.prepareStatement("insert into MSH_Total_Stock_heads(producer, iin, bin, kato, f_014110, send_log_id) " +
                        "values(?,?,?,?,?,?)");
                for(int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
                    ps.setString(1, request.getProducer());
                    ps.setString(2, request.getIin());
                    ps.setString(3, request.getBin());
                    ps.setString(4, request.getKato());
                    ps.setString(5, request.getDataValues().getServiceDataStructModelOfInt32().get(0).getValue());
ps.setInt(6, sendLogId);
                    ps.addBatch();
                }
                ps.executeBatch();
            }
```

это код Класса `request`.

```
@Element(name = "ServiceDataStructModelOfInt32", required = false)
        private List<Request.DataValues.ServiceDataStructModelOfInt32> serviceDataStructModelOfInt32 = new ArrayList<Request.DataValues.ServiceDataStructModelOfInt32>();

        public List<ServiceDataStructModelOfInt32> getServiceDataStructModelOfInt32() {
            return serviceDataStructModelOfInt32;
        }

        public void setServiceDataStructModelOfInt32(List<ServiceDataStructModelOfInt32> serviceDataStructModelOfInt32) {
            this.serviceDataStructModelOfInt32 = serviceDataStructModelOfInt32;
        }

        @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
        @XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
                "Key",
                "Value"
        })
```

это ошибка

```
org.simpleframework.xml.core.InstantiationException: Cannot instantiate interface java.util.List for field 'serviceDataStructModelOfInt32' private java.util.List kz.estat.bdad.msh_parser
```

Comment: Попробуйте `NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("ServiceDataStructModelOfInt32");`
См. http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-dom-parser/

Comment: По всей видимости, вы используете аннотацию `@Element`, тогда как нужно - `@ElementList`

Comment: так тоже пробовал тогда возникает другая ошибка 'ServiceDataStructModelOfInt32' is already used with @org.simpleframework.xml.Element(name=ServiceDataStructModelOfInt32, type=void, data=false, required=false) on field 'ServiceDataStructModelOfInt32'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
@Root(name = "DataValues")
public class DataList {
  @ElementList(name = "DataValues", inline = true, required = false)
  private List<ServiceDataStructModelOfInt32> dataValues;

  public List<ServiceDataStructModelOfInt32> getDataValues() {
    return dataValues;
  }
}

@Root(name = "ServiceDataStructModelOfInt32")
public class ServiceDataStructModelOfInt32 {
  @Element(name = "Key")
  private String key;

  @Element(name = "Value")
  private int value; 

  public String getKey() {
    return key;
  }

  public String getValue() {
    return value;
  }
}
```

Comment: пробовал  Element 'ServiceDataStructModelOfInt32' does not have a match in class kz.estat.bdad.msh_parser.Request$DataValues теперь такая ошибка

Comment: Немного поправил ответ. Попробуйте добавить атрибут `inline = true`

Comment: org.simpleframework.xml.core.ConstructorException: Can not construct inner class kz.estat.bdad.msh_parser.Request$ServiceDataStructModelOfInt32

Comment: Судя по исключению, вы объявили класс `ServiceDataStructModelOfInt32` внутри другого класса. Вынесите его в отдельный файл. Либо попробуйте добавить модификатор `static`, но я не знаю, способен ли SimpleFramework работать с вложенными статическими классами.

Comment: вы меня прям спасли все заработало добавил static